# Could not find a JavaToKotlinConversionProvider

Tags: android-studio

I'm not able to create a new project in the android studio. I am getting a warning message

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not find a
>   JavaToKotlinConversionProvider, even though one should be bundled with
>   Studio    at
>   com.android.tools.idea.npw.model.JavaToKotlinHandler.getJavaToKotlinConversionProvider(JavaToKotlinHandler.java:56)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.npw.template.TemplateValueInjector.addKotlinVersion(TemplateValueInjector.java:410)

Comment: You're not alone. Since upgrading to Android Studio 3.3 I get this same error when attempting to create a new project from the Startup Screen, or from the File menu.
The process creates the project folder and a '.idea' folder with a single file 'workspace.xml' That's all.

Answer (score 16):

Go to `Preferences -> Plugins -> Kotlin` and update the Kotlin plugin to the last version even though you don't write your code in Kotlin.

[image: Preferences]

Comment: @MehdiDehghani So Kotlin plugin is disabled. Activate it and then update it.

Answer (score 5):

I have the same error, I've juste disabled the kotlin plugin and after restarting the IDE, just re-enable it. After that final restart, every thing works fine.

Answer (score 4):

Go to file and the plugin in android studio and update your Kotlin plugin...

[image: Image lacks any useful description]

Answer (score 2):

I opened an old project (*by old I mean another project*) and did everything Android Studio said to give me a successful build (I faced some errors when I tried to build the project that I could build couple weeks ago and actually I fixed them, updating gradle and stuff like that, not code issues of course).

After that I could create new project same as before.

**Update** seems like in order to keep Android Studio happy we have to keep Kotlin plugin enabled, interesting.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by doing this:

1. File->Settings->Plugins
2. Click the ***Installed*** tab at the top.
3. Search "kotlin" and click the result that shows up.
4. Click ***Enable*** at the top right

Answer (score 1):

settings>plugins>check Kotlin >Apply then Ok solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

It occurred due to migration from Android Studio 3.2 to 3.3
Goto File-->Invalidate Caches/Restart

This will solve the problem.